# Using angular, how can I change a div's background image to match my user object's profileImage property?

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-class

Once my user logs in to my site, a user object is successfully getting attached to my controller's scope as $scope.user that looks a bit like this (simplified for clarity):

```
{
username: user2016
  , email: "user@user.com"
  , password: "hashedpasswordhere"
  , name: "A. User"
  , profileImage: "http://www.userpic.com"
}
```

Here is the related css:

```
.pic {
  height: 2.5em;
  width: 2.5em;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://www.userpic.com");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I want the currently logged in user to have their previously selected profile pic displayed in the top right when they are logged in, and I want to use angularJS to accomplish this. Obviously in the above CSS I have just manually plugged in the correct url, but if a different user logs in, I'm out of luck. After reading the ngClass docs I am still confused. Is there another directive I should be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) directive to set `background-image`:

```
<div class="pic" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(' + user.profileImage + ')'}"></div>
```

Comment: I tried this solution but the div is now empty. I think you are forgetting the url() portion maybe? Still can't get it to work. Tinkering now.

Comment: ```<div class="pic" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url({{user.profileImage}})'}"></div>``` works! Thanks!

Comment: @devigner Check updated answer, I indeed forgot url part. But you don't need `{{ }}`.

Comment: Well `{'background-image': 'url(' + user.profileImage + ')'}` is basically normal javascript object syntax. However, with `'url({{user.profileImage}})'` angular will have to set up one more binding to update `user.profileImage` part. I don't think it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know about a directive that could fix it, at least not a out-of-the-box one. But you can do something like this:

```
<div class='pic' style='background-image: url( "{{user.profileImage}}" );'></div>
```

You could have a placeholder image loaded into the `pic2` class so that one gets displayed by default, and use the angular two-way data bindding to change the style of the picture.

Another option is to use an `img` tag in combination with the `ng-src` angular directive.

```
<img ng-src='{{user.profileImage}}'>
```

He is the documentation for the [`ng-src`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) directive.

Comment: Combining your and dfsq input proved effective!
```<div class="pic" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url({{user.profileImage}})'}"></div>``` works.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
  <div class="pic" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url({{user.profileImage}})'}"></div>
```